# Drag & Drop in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, drag

I am looking for WPF MVVM solution to drag and drop **within** as well as accross different listboxes.

Drag and Dropping Within Listboxes would update the sequence or Order.

I came across the Gong Soloution one which unfornately does not support both.

Also dragging something off (into nowhere) a listbox would remove the item would be really nice to have.

Comment: ViewModels care nothing of dragging and dropping.  It is entirely the concern of the view.

Comment: Agree, How would you handle drag and drop between listboxes having disparate data structures.

Comment: With dread and trepidation.  Drag/drop is a basterd.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend looking into [Bea Stollnitz's article](https://web.archive.org/web/20151107025019/http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/488) on Drag/Drop. If her drag/drop code doesn't do what you need, it is very easy to add on to

Comment: did go thru. it, however it does not fit my requirements, For now I am using Gong Solutions which does not support both Drag and drop within and across listbox's

Comment: @bonitzenator Updated to a wayback machine link